# How to presents javascript code with variable in executeScript method?

Tags: javascript, selenium, dom, selenium-webdriver

I am implementing selenium script, by executing javascript code with method executeScript. In which getting issue with single(') and Double quotes(") while passing variable.

**Not Working:**

```
js.executeScript("return document.querySelector('input[value=\" '"+group_name+"' \"]').value;").toString();
```

**Working with static value:**

```
js.executeScript("return document.querySelector('input[value=\" DemoTest \"]').value;").toString();
```

Here `('input[value=\" '"+group_name+"' \"]')`  group_name variable is covered by Java variable quotes,

**So By technically its 3 Quotes which need to pass** 

 1. Before return statement " " 
 2. On querySelector '' 
 3. Passing variable value to querySelector " "

Please Note: DOM only accepts if it has been passed through different Quotes with inner strings 2 and 3.

Here I am getting SyntaxError from DOM: Its says `SyntaxError : missing ) after argument list`

So How can I pass variable in such a way where DOM accepts it with required syntax.

Comment: the `'` in here `value=\" '"+group_name+"' \"` are to much, aren't they?

Comment: could be type casting issue. if you see your dynamic code you are using single quote before the variable value and its not showing in static value. may be you can try via changing the single quote

Comment: using selenium, you can leverage the new string option of the ` `js.executeScript(\` return ${ group_name} \`)` -- well, at least if you're using it with node.js. If you're in Java, I an uncertain.

Comment: \" Text \" is the ultimate way for " " Double Quotes.
And ' " + variable value " ' is Java syntax to pass variable.

Comment: @Andersson "and also you need to do something with those quotes" Thats the whole point....

Comment: @IshitaShah Java is not Javascript.

Comment: @Feathercrown Using Selenium Automation Framework with Java + Web Page Server side handling with Javascript

Comment: Ah ok. I'm just used to people mixing them up, a situation where they are actually both used is rarer. :P

Comment: Why not simply call `driver.findElement(by.css('input[value=' + JSON.stringify(group_name) + ']')).getAttribute('value')` ? It would be easier to maintain and you'll get an explicit error if the element is missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use below code:

```
js.executeScript("return document.querySelector('input[value=\"' + arguments[0] + '\"]').value;", group_name).toString();
```

Comment: You need to remove the `+`s and spaces next to `arguments[0]`, no? e.g. `[value='arguments[0]']`.

Comment: No. String concatenation in JavaScript works as `"string" + stringVariable + "string"` ... or did you mean something else?

Comment: Yeah, you are right... I was thinking string concat with `"` from the start of the string but it's string concat inside the string with `'` for JS. My bad...

Comment: @Andersson Its not working, its taking value as like other options, It says "invalid element state: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'input[value= AutoTest Group ]' is not a valid selector. " It means DOM still wants Double Quotes " " on variable value.

Comment: Yep. That's because you're trying to pass value with spaces... Try updated answer